# Javascript (JQuery) Variable Overwriting Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{       
var settings_image ={
    url:"<?php echo site_url('/cms/editor/upload/images');?>",
    method: "POST",
    fileName: "file",
    returnType:"json",
    onSelect:function(files)
    {
        var folder = prompt("Please enter sub-folder name for these images. If you do not enter anything, images will be uploaded to the root images folder", "");
        if (folder != null) {
            url:"<?php echo site_url('/cms/editor/upload/images');?>/"+folder;
        }
    }
  };
}); 
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is when the windows prompt is shown on selecting the files (inside onSelect function), if user enters something, then the URL property defined as first step above should be rewritten with the new value with folder in the path. The URL property is basically calling the php script to upload the file.

How to rewrite the URL property from that if block?

Comment: `this.url="<?php echo site_url('/cms/editor/upload/images');?>/"+folder;`

Comment: `settings_image.url = "<?php echo site_url('/cms/editor/upload/images');?>/"+folder;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this` for current reference.

```
var settings_image ={
    url:"<?php echo site_url('/cms/editor/upload/images');?>",
    method: "POST",
    fileName: "file",
    returnType:"json",
    onSelect:function(files)
    {
        var folder = prompt("Please enter sub-folder name for these images. If you do not enter anything, images will be uploaded to the root images folder", "");
        if (folder != null) {
            this.url="<?php echo site_url('/cms/editor/upload/images');?>/"+folder;//resetting url
        }
    }
  };
```